# Why did my Excalibur go all explodey on me?

Tags: nethack

So I was a lawful human Valkyrie...just picked up Excalibur a few floors prior, and had started working through the Gnomish Mines.

I hadn't done anything to anger Tyr, I was simply cutting away some rock in the mines to make it easier to get between staircases.  I was stressed from just picking up some dwarvish gear, and all of a sudden I was blasted by Excalibur when I equipped it.

What what what happened?

Comment: Are you *still* a lawful human Valkyrie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you were not Lawful or you had a negative [alignment record](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Alignment_record) (from displeasing your god) at the time you attempted to equip the artifact. See the linked article for a list of the numerous ways you can piss off a deity.

Comment: Could also be being polymorphed into a demon, since Excalibur is anti-demon.

Comment: @Grace - Good call. Forgot about that.

Comment: I was a lawful Valkyrie.  This action actually ended up killing her...the report at the end didn't give me much to go on (basically I was the same alignment as when I started).

Comment: @espais: The messages after death should have included something like "You strayed/sinned/transgressed". Do you have a dumplog?

Comment: I don't actually...I've since restarted.  I don't remember seeing anything like that, but who knows, maybe I missed it.  This answer seems the most reasonable.

Answer (score -3):

The only character that does not get blasted by excalibur when you equip it is a Knight.  He's the only one having any business wielding it anyway...  Not that it stops me from using it if I'm a lawful character.  You just need to make sure your hit points are up when you equip it.

Comment: In vanilla Nethack, there's nothing class-prohibitive about Excalibur. I've run countless Samurai and Valkyrie games and gotten Excalibur without being blasted.